# Failed to install Pytorch Snippets and Librosa in VScode - Apple M1

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch, librosa

I anticipate I'm not an expert in informatics. I used to run PyTorch snippets for some deep learning on my old MacBook Pro (2015), but now I have Apple's last Pro, and have troubles with installing packages in VScode. Two of these packages give me trouble: PyTorch snippets and Librosa. PyTorch Snippets can be installed from the "extensions" in the VScode menu; that is what I did, and used to do with my old Mac. This time, however, when I import torch within an .ipynb instance I get the error **"No module named 'torch'"**.

With Librosa, when I run in the terminal `pip3 install librosa` at some point I get this error:

**Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: numba, llvmlite
Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error**

, then a long list of red things, then again:

**ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build numba llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, threadpoolctl, scipy, requests, numba, joblib, appdirs, soundfile, scikit-learn, resampy, pooch, audioread, librosa
Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:**

Do you experienced anything similar? Do you have some hint? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix described in
https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/693#issuecomment-909501195

```
arch -arm64 brew install llvm@11
LLVM_CONFIG="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm@11/11.1.0_2/bin/llvm-config" arch -arm64 pip install llvmlite
```